# How to change week start date using df.resample?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using Python 3.6 and this is my code:

```
trainFile = r'C:\download\combine\Combine_1.csv'
pwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(trainFile))
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(trainFile))
os.chdir(pwd)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
week = df.resample('w').mean()

week.to_csv('week_combine.csv')
```

I try to make daily data into weekly data, but now the week starts at every Sunday, how can I change it into every Monday?

For example, now the results look like:

```
...
2017-09-10
2017-09-17
2017-09-24
...
```

but I want to change it into:

```
...
2017-09-11
2017-09-18
2017-09-25
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need `W-MON` [anchored offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-09-09', periods=15)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(15)}, index=rng)  


week = df.resample('W-MON').mean()
print (week)
             a
2017-09-11   1
2017-09-18   6
2017-09-25  12
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: By default the week starts on Sunday. Is there any way to groupby weekly starting from today?

Comment: @EMT - Do you think `Thursday` ?

Comment: Not specifically thursday, I want to group by weekly in a way that whenever the program will run, the day it is running it will be the default starting day.

Comment: as example, if I run it today, the groupby will show values for '2021-10-21, 2021-10-14 and so on'.

If it is run on tomorrow, then it will show grouped values for  '2021-10-22, 2021-10-15 and so on'.

Comment: @EMT - I think best post new question with sample data, expected ouput and your code (should be copied code from this answer). thanks.

Comment: Can't post any question. Blocked because I could not perfectly explain my few previous 
 questions. Anyway, thanks. I noticed for a long time your contribute to any pandas related questions and appreciate it very much.

Comment: @EMT check `start = '2017-09-09'
rng = pd.date_range('2017-09-09', periods=15)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(15)}, index=rng)  

a = (df.index - pd.to_datetime(start)).days // 7


df = df.reset_index().groupby(a).agg(day=('index', 'first'), new = ('a', 'mean'))`

Comment: it worked! Kudos. It would have been nicer if pandas had a keyword as "W-NOW" or "W-TODAY".